# How to design library to be accessible from all activities in Android application?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity, android-library

I'm making an `Android` library which accepts data from the user and does some background work.

Right now, the class which directly interacts with the client app has private objects and public static methods for the client app to call (I chose static over the `singleton pattern`). It also requires the client app to call an `initialize()` method the first time they use the library.

This relies on the client app knowing which activity is called first. If their application can start on a number of different activities, that raises an issue.

My options:

1. Force user to initialize in every activity, and internally maintain whether the library has already been initialized or not.
2. Follow a different design pattern.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? What is good design practice for a library?

Comment: There is something called the application class in android. This class is common for all the activities. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Try lazily initializing it when a method is used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) is what I was looking for. Thanks amalBit.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a safe assumption to think that a developer would know what activity will start the application, but if someone decided to use your library in a case where they didn't know, you could make the initialize process somewhat intelligent.

For instance, you could add a boolean flag in the library which keeps track of whether or not it has been initialized. In this way you can have some function that returns this value. If it's true, the library has already been initialized, if not initialize it.

It seems a bit bulky, but it would take nothing more than a simple if statement in the onCreate() function of any potential startup activities, if the library isn't initialized, then initialize it.

Or perhaps make it so that the user can call the initialize function as many times as they want, but keep track of that boolean value. Put the if statement in the initialize function and if it's already initialized, do nothing.

In this way, all the programmer would have to do is place a

```
someLibrary.initialize();
```

in each onCreate() method of each Activity in question. Once it's actually initialized, each subsequent call does nothing.

Also, on a side note, it may be worth your while to try to change your code in such a way that an initialize method is not necessary. What exactly does the initialize function do?